# AssertionError: Expected event "RaffleEnter" to be emited, but it doesn't exist in the contract

Tags: hardhat, unittesting, chai

I'm working on freeCodeCamp.org's [Learn Blockchain, Solidity, and Full Stack Web3 Development with JavaScript – 32-Hour Course](https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ)

I have the following contract code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol";

error Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
error Raffle__TransferFailed();
error Raffle__NotOpen();
error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

/** @title A Sample Raffle Contract
 *  @author solvman
 *  @notice this contract is for creating decentralized lottery contract
 */

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    /* Types */
    enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    }

    /* State Variables*/
    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    /* Lottery Variables */
    address private s_recentWinner;
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;

    /* Events */
    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint256 entranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
        }
        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
            revert Raffle__NotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
        // Emit an event when we update a dynamic array or mapping
        // Named events with function name reversed
        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    ) public override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
        bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval;
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        bool unpkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external {
        // Request the random number
        // Once we get it , do something with it
        // 2 transaction process
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(address(this).balance, s_players.length, uint256(s_raffleState));
        }

        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256, uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override {
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;

        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_entranceFee;
    }

    function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_recentWinner;
    }

    function getRaffleState() public view returns (RaffleState) {
        return s_raffleState;
    }

    function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return NUM_WORDS;
    }

    function getNumberOfPlayer() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_players.length;
    }

    function getLatestTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_lastTimeStamp;
    }

    function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
    }

    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }
}
```

My unit test looks as follows:

```js
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");
const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, ethers, network } = require("hardhat");
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config");

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
  ? dscribe.skip
  : describe("Raffle Unit Tests:", async function () {
      let raffle, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, raffleEntranceFee, deployer;
      const chainId = network.config.chainId;

      beforeEach(async function () {
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
        await deployments.fixture(["all"]);
        raffle = await ethers.getContract("Raffle", deployer);
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", deployer);
        raffleEntranceFee = await raffle.getEntranceFee();
      });

      describe("constructor", async function () {
        it("initializes the raffle correctly", async function () {
          const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState();
          const interval = await raffle.getInterval();
          assert.equal(raffleState.toString(), "0");
          assert.equal(interval.toString(), networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]);
        });
      });

      describe("enter raffle", async function () {
        it("reverts if you don't pay enough", async function () {
          await expect(raffle.enterRaffle()).to.be.revertedWith("Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered");
        });
        it("records players when they enter", async function () {
          await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee });
          const playerFromContract = await raffle.getPlayer(0);
          assert.equal(playerFromContract, deployer);
        });
        it("emits event on enter", async function () {
          await expect(raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })).to.emit(raffle, "RaffleEnter");
        });
      });
    });
```

The last test fails with the following error:

**AssertionError: Expected event "RaffleEnter" to be emitted, but it doesn't exist in the contract. Please make sure you've compiled its latest version before running the test.**

I've tried removing the artifacts folder and recompiling the contract. The event is clearly present in the contract code. Why do I get the error?